# Storing separate data and group on common key

Tags: c#, generics, multidimensional-array

Working with an API that can handle multiple connections (i.e. sessions), each of these sessions has a uniqueID (sessionID) and keeps track of all inbound and outbound messages via sequence numbers.

Class1

```
public void Method1(SessionID sessionID, Message message)
{       
    var ID = sessionID;
    var foo = message.InSeqNo;
}

public void Method2(SessionID sessionID, Message message)
{
    var ID = SessionID;
    var bar = message.OutSeqNo;
}
```

I'm curious how would you recommend storing this data together so each instance can be displayed independently based on its sessionID.

There is no need to store previous numbers because they are only displayed.
None of the SessionIDs will change and each sequence number will update independently.

The best thing I can think of is using two separate fields like `Dictionary<sessionID, number>`, .Clear each field on update, re-add with new values, then join the two via LINQ and display the information.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to keep track of.  You want to keep track of the next in/out sequence number for each session?  Or ... something else?

Comment: @Jim Correct, Im going to try your solution today (sorry I was sick yesterday), but it sounds like you deciphered what I was trying to say. Right now each session is displaying the same in/out seq number which I know is not true.  Im going to try the new class and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a single class that contains the inbound and outbound sequence numbers for a particular ID?

```
class SessionInfo
{
    public int SessionId { get; private set; }
    public int InSeqNo { get; set; }
    public int OutSeqNo { get; set; }
}
```

Dictionary Sessions = new Dictionary();

To update a session's InSeqNo, then:

```
SessionInfo sess;
if (Sessions.TryGetValue(sessionId, out sess))
{
    ++sess.InSeqNo;
}
```

Or am I missing something fundamental in your question?